# Aggregating data at different levels within a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am working with a data frame where the data are stored at a lower level. Each row is a case and each column an outcome. I want to aggregate this data to two higher levels without losing the original information. The data look like this:

```
set.seed(301)
df <- data.frame(
  level1 = c(1:20),
  level2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11),
  level3 = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 2)),
  a = round(runif(20, 10000, 20000)),
  b = round(runif(20, 0, 100)),
  c = round(runif(20, 0, 1000)),
  d = round(runif(20, 50000, 90000))
)
```

Which produces the following:

```
   level1 level2 level3     a  b   c     d
1       1      1      1 15971 98 183 64768
2       2      1      1 11322 72 355 75087
3       3      2      1 10021 82 638 86030
4       4      2      1 17540 37 557 73085
5       5      3      1 16141 45 809 66978
6       6      3      1 14337 56 228 75227
7       7      3      1 16648 31 468 74257
8       8      3      1 19809 53 108 68250
9       9      4      2 14344 20  44 68319
10     10      5      2 18439 47 200 77471
11     11      5      2 17576 65 672 71247
12     12      5      2 16972 12 148 89347
13     13      6      2 14986 47  54 70600
14     14      6      2 14492 22 903 71335
15     15      7      3 10702 70 818 70757
16     16      8      3 16815 70 182 71346
17     17      9      3 14595 39 722 62427
18     18      9      3 14407 47 323 80146
19     19     10      4 17453 68 144 72299
20     20     11      4 17332 64 559 53931
```

I am looking for a way to create eight new columns that aggregate a - d (which are at level 1) to level 2 and level 3. So the finished data frame would have 8 new columns for a total of 15 columns. Four would have a - d aggregated to level 2 and four would have a - d aggregated to level three.

I know this will create redundancy in many of the rows (especially at level 3), but this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(level2) %>%
  mutate(a_lvl2 = sum(a), 
         b_lvl2 = sum(b), 
         c_lvl2 = sum(c), 
         d_lvl2 = sum(d)) %>%
  group_by(level3) %>%
  mutate(a_lvl3 = sum(a), 
         b_lvl3 = sum(b), 
         c_lvl3 = sum(c), 
         d_lvl3 = sum(d))
```

Answer (score 2):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, a_level2 := sum(a), by = level2]
```

With Base R

```
agg <- aggregate(a ~ level2, data=df, FUN=sum)
names(agg)[2] <- "a_level2"
df <- merge(df, agg, by="level2")
```

With Tidyverse/dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(level2) %>% 
    summarise(a_level2 = sum(a)) %>% 
    right_join(df, by="level2")
```